# Exporting file from database to csv,space removed in between the field name

Tags: php, mysql, csv

While exporting file to CSV, space in the field "`Sr. No`", is removed after dot of "`Sr.`". I don't want that space to be removed. The code is as follow:

```
        $filename = "file.csv";
        $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');           
        $array = array('Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address');
        $header = str_replace(' ', '', $array);
        header('Content-type: application/csv');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$filename);
        fputcsv($fp, $header);
        $query = "select * from registratin";
        $result = mssql_query($query);
        $i = 1;
        while($row = mssql_fetch_row($result)) {
          $row = array_merge(array($i), $row);
          fputcsv($fp, $row);
          $i++;
        }
```

Comment: `str_replace` is replacing all spaces from the elements in that `$array`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
$array = array('Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address');
$header = str_replace(' ', '', $array);
```

With this:

```
$header = ['Sr. No.','Name','DOB','Address'];
```

I am a bit baffled as to why that str_replace call is there.